# nginx -> serve different files using try_files based on cookies (conditions, if, then, else)

Tags: nginx, ssl, rewrite, https, http-cookie

I need to configure an nginx server so that:
If user has a specific cookie so the server must send a file, else the server must send another one. I read plenty of related articles, but nothing helped, also I know that there is some issues when `try_files` meets `location if` but how to resolve this...

I have an example, which should be working, but not in fact:

```
upstream site {
    server localhost:4321;
}

server {

    listen *:1234;
    server_name site.com;
    root /path/www/;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/ssl.key;

    location = / {

        set $variable /path/index.html;

        if ($http_cookie ~* "someCookie=someValue(?:;|$)") {
            set $index_file /path2/index.html;
        }

        rewrite .* $index_file break;

        try_files  $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @site;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way, not sure the best solution, but it does work.

```
location @rewrite {
    if ($http_cookie ~* "someCookie=someValue(?:;|$)") {
        rewrite .* /path1/file1.html last;
    }
    rewrite .* /path2/file2.html last;
}

location = / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @rewrite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ($cookie_myCookieNameIsBlaBlaBla ~* "cookieValueThatIWannaMatch") {
   # my logic in here
}
```

Just remember that according to nginx's documentation, if is evil, so be careful.

More info:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Cya!

Comment: It doesn't differ so much from my example of code above and it will not solve the issue...